# Cannot open Office documents in SharePoint SSE

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We have a SharePoint Server edition solution where, until, recently, users are unable to open Office documents inside the browser. Doing so will result in that "something is wrong with the configuration".

I have checked and can see Office Online service is running (also tried to restart it). I can ping the OOS server from the admin server.The OOS shows as "healthy".

What can I do to debug/solve this issue? In admin center, we have this reported issue in category "configuraition" which I am not sure if its related (With timestap a few days after the issue occured):

*[MissingFeature] Database [SP_Extra_Content_Common] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]. Feature (Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]) is referenced in database [SP_Extra_Content_Common], but isn't installed on the current farm. The missing feature might cause upgrade to fail. If necessary, please install any solution that contains the feature and restart upgrade.
[MissingFeature] Database [SP_Extra_Content_Common] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [744b5fd3-3b09-4da6-9bd1-de18315b045d]. Feature (Id = [744b5fd3-3b09-4da6-9bd1-de18315b045d]) is referenced in database [SP_Extra_Content_Common], but isn't installed on the current farm. The missing feature might cause upgrade to fail. If necessary, please install any solution that contains the feature and restart upgrade.
[MissingAssembly] Assembly [Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Application, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c] is referenced in the database [SP_Extra_Content_Common], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this assembly. One or more assemblies are referenced in the database [SP_Extra_Content_Common], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these assemblies.*

*[MissingFeature] Database [SP_Extra_Content_DMS_00] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]. Feature (Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]) is referenced in database [SP_Extra_Content_DMS_00], but isn't installed on the current farm. The missing feature might cause upgrade to fail. If necessary, please install any solution that contains the feature and restart upgrade.*

*[MissingFeature] Database [SP_Extra_Content_DMS_01] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]. Feature (Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]) is referenced in database [SP_Extra_Content_DMS_01], but isn't installed on the current farm. The missing feature might cause upgrade to fail. If necessary, please install any solution that contains the feature and restart upgrade.*

*[MissingFeature] Database [SP_Extra_Content_DMS_02] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]. Feature (Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]) is referenced in database [SP_Extra_Content_DMS_02], but isn't installed on the current farm. The missing feature might cause upgrade to fail. If necessary, please install any solution that contains the feature and restart upgrade.*

*[MissingFeature] Database [SP_Extra_Content_DMS_03] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]. Feature (Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364]) is referenced in database [SP_Extra_Content_DMS_03], but isn't installed on the current farm. The missing feature might cause upgrade to fail. If necessary, please install any solution that contains the feature and restart upgrade.*

Could above be related to the issue with opening documents? How to solve this?

Comment: Have you recently installed any Windows or SharePoint updates on your SharePoint servers?